# Как выбрать элементы списка в цикле с интервалом

Tags: python, list

У меня имеется список, в котором есть числа: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10. Также у меня имеется пустой список, в который я должен добавить выбранные числа из первого.
Каким образом мне в цикле выбрать числа с интервалом для присвоения?

Это моя первая программа на питоне и я профан в данном ЯП.
К примеру в C# я сделал бы это следующим образом:

```
int j = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i += 2) {
    array2[j] = array1[i];
    j++
}
```

Подобным кодом я бы получил интервал в одно значение списка между числами. Как я могу организовать нечто подобное в python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хотите именно "По-питонски", а не "с помощью Python но на C#":

```
lt1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
lt2 = lt1[::2]
print(lt2)

[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за правильную версию :-)

Answer (score 1):

идентичный код:

```
j = 0
for i in range(0, len(array1), 2):
    array2[j] = array1[i]
    j += 1
```